# excluding url pattern from django app..is it possible?

Tags: python, django

So I use a django app for my project.
Let's say we called it *otherapp*

Include otherapp urls in my project urls:

```
url(r'^other/', include('otherapp.urls'))
```

but there's one url pattern in *otherapp.urls* that I don't want to include for some reason.

Is it possible?

Comment: Can you elaborate the problem? I am not sure, you don't want to include the otherapp's url in project or you don't want to include an url which exists in otherapp's url?

Comment: @ruddra the later one

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are **two ways** to do this:

A. Just **define all urls** here which you want to include. (but this is **so not DRY**)

**OR**

B. Define the url here which you want to **exclude and raise 404** on it. (a little **hackish**): e.g.

```
     urlpatterns = ('',
       url('^other/url/to/exclude', django.views.defaults.page_not_found),
       url(r'^other/', include('otherapp.urls')),
     )
```

Comment: There is nothing hackish about this at all. +1 from me.

Comment: using manage.py show_urls the url pattern that I want to exclude will have two different views, is that okay?

Comment: Yeah thats perfectly fine,, django always picks up the first url pattern it matches in urls.py... I do this all the time to shut off unwanted urls of third party apps.

Comment: In [django 1.9, the `page_not_found` needs an exception parameter.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/views/#django.views.defaults.page_not_found)

I ended up having something along the lines of

`url('^other/url/to/exclude', django.views.defaults.page_not_found, {'exception': Exception()}),`

Answer (score 4):

You can look at the imported URLs and modify them via any means you'd like.

The easiest would be by checking the `url.name`, but you could look by matching the `regex` as well via `url.regex`

```
from otherapp.urls import urlpatterns as other_urlpatterns

url(r'^other/', include([url for url in other_urlpatterns if url.name != 'some-urlpattern']))


url(r'^other/', include([url for url in other_urlpatterns if url.regex.pattern != r'^some-pattern/$']))
```

Comment: manage.py show_urls (from django-extensions) won't run using either of these methods.  Error 'RegexURLPattern' object is not callable

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from otherapp import view

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^other/$', 'views.methodname'),

]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I tried in this way to solve this problem:

```
 from otherapp.urls import urlpatterns as other_app_urls
 idxs = [0, 3, 4] #assuming 2nd and 3rd url you want to ignore
 urlpatterns = ('',
      url(r'^other/', include([other_app_urls[i] for i in idxs]),
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

I've create this function for exclude some url's of other apps.

```
def exclude_urls(urlpatterns, exclude):
    if isinstance(urlpatterns, list):
        for u in urlpatterns[:]:
            if isinstance(u, RegexURLResolver):
                exclude_urls(u, exclude)
            elif u.name in exclude:
                urlpatterns.remove(u)
    elif isinstance(urlpatterns, RegexURLResolver):
        exclude_urls(urlpatterns.url_patterns, exclude)
    else: # module
        exclude_urls(urlpatterns.urlpatterns, exclude)
    return urlpatterns

exclude = ["foo", "bar"]
urlpatterns = patterns(
    "",
    url(r"", include(exclude_urls(app_urls, exclude))),
)
```